# Digital Ocean: One Click Django Won't Route My Domain, Bad Gateway

Tags: python, django, nginx, gunicorn, digital-ocean

The one click django with ubuntu 16, nginx, and gunicorn is not routing my domain name. When I type the IP address into the address bar it works but when when I use the domain I get `502 Bad Gateway nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)`. Looking at the nginx error log I see:

`2017/10/16 19:05:18 [error] 23017#23017: *80 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client:` redacted `server: _, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/home/django/gunicorn.socket:/"`

I followed the steps here:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-point-to-digitalocean-nameservers-from-common-domain-registrars#registrar-godaddy

and here:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-host-name-with-digitalocean

But I must have done something wrong. Anyone have any ideas how to solve this. I am brand new to DO, Django, and really web dev.

Answer (score 0):

updating NS servers take up to 48 hours. If you already updated 48 hours ago, then clear browser cache then again access to your domain. Normally after 24 hours, you can access to your domain over the browser. Secondly, check the access to `/etc/nginx/sites-available`

Comment: 48 hours is a long time and it has not been that long but when i `whois [domain]` it points to the ns1,2,3.digitalocean servers. in sites-available and sites-enabled I have tried `server_name [mydomain]`. I bought the domain from google and the tests they recommend on DO seemed to work a lot faster than they anticipated they would.

Comment: Whois can show that domain NS was updated. But to work properly it must update in all DNS server which takes maximum 48 hours. To be honest I memorized I had a problem with Namecheap. Even after 48 hours, they didn't fix that properly. After contacting to customer service they solved my issue. Try to ping yourdomain.com and see which Ip address it shows. if it is updated already it must show your host in digitalocean or any cloud services. Secondly, if you use Linux cd /etc/nginx/sites-available and delete defaults.

Answer (score 0):

Your upstream in the nginx configs is wrong, see the nginx log: `http://unix:/....` ? It should be either `http://...` or `unix:/...` - depends on how your Django setup is configured.

Check your nginx configs in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/` or `/etc/nginx/conf.d` and fix the location of the upstream and reload nginx to fix the issue.